# How to solve the equation $5\sin x=12\cos x$?

Tags: trigonometry

(I'm only a Year 7 so please tell me exactly how you found the solution)

Find the value of ***x*** when 5 *sin* ***x***=12 *cos* ***x***.

Round your number to the nearest degree.

I started by dividing both sides by *cos* ***x*** and then by 5 to get *sin* ***x***/*cos* ***x*** but then I got stuck. I know that equation equals *tan* ***x*** but is that any help?

Comment: You have $\tan(x)=\dfrac{12}{5}\implies x=\arctan\left(\dfrac{12}{5}\right)$.

Comment: Is everyone here going to ignore the fact that the tangens function is periodic, thus there is more than one solution? (Even in the interval $[0,2\pi]$)

Comment: Year 7 is a young age to tackle such a problem.  That is not in itself  a bad thing but solving $\tan x =2.4 $ is the easier part and suggests to me you might be rushing through content without consolidating topics properly. Better in my opinion to take things slower and look at interesting maths that isn't linked to any specific content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given is $$5\sin(x)=12\cos(x)$$ dividing by $$\cos(x)\ne 0$$ we obtain
$$5\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=12$$ dividing by $5$ we get
$$\tan(x)=\frac{12}{5}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: I 've heard that I need to use arctan but why

Comment: that is the inverse function of $\tan(x)$

Comment: You need to use $arctan$ in order to find out the angle $x$ for which $tan(x) = \frac{12}{5}$

Answer (score 0):

$ 5\sin x = 12 \cos x$

The only thing we need to be careful of, is that we don't divide by $0$. If we take $\cos x = 0$ we see that it isn't a solution to this equation, so we're okay to divide by $\cos x$.

Then we get $5\frac{\sin x}{\ cos x} = 12$

Now we divide both sides by $5$, and we note that $\frac{\sin x}{\ cos x} = \tan x$

$\tan x = \frac{12}{5}$

Now since your in year $7$, I will assume you are only looking for the "principal value" of $x$. Using your calculator, you can use the $arctan$ function on $\frac{12}{5}$ and round your answer to get $67$ degrees to the nearest degree.

Edit: "$arctan$" is defined as the inverse of $\tan$, that is to say, if $\tan x = y$, then $arctan(y) = x$